# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'desktop.ini'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os, subprocess, configparser

# Search for folder!
# First locate the directory
root_dir = input("Enter the root directory you wanna enter:")
try:
    os.chdir(root_dir)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("ERROR:Directory not found")
    exit(505)
# second locate the folder now!
folder_name = input("Enter the name of folder you wanna hide:")

# Hiding part starts now!
# check the entered information
# Start by checking if the folder is present in the directory
check_dir = os.listdir(root_dir)
print(check_dir)
if folder_name in check_dir:
    # If the folder is present lets hide it!

    # step 1: Give a hidden name(No-Break space) by pressing alt + 0160
    folder = ' '
    os.rename(folder_name, folder)

    # step 2: Enter the properties of this folder
    # first change the folder to read only using cmd
    subprocess.call('cd' + " " + root_dir, shell=True)
    cmd_command = "attrib +s" + " " + folder
    returned = subprocess.call(cmd_command, shell=True)
    print("Shell returned", returned)
    # second change the folder icon with desktop.ini and configParser
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config['.ShellClassInfo'] = {
        'ConfirmFileOp': '0',
        'NoSharing': '1',
        'IconFile': 'Folder.ico',
        'IconIndex': '0',
        'InfoTip': 'This is folder man'
    }
    with open("desktop.ini", "wt") as configFile:
        config.write(configFile)
else:
    print("ERROR: folder not present!!!")

# Check At the end for success
print(os.listdir(root_dir))
```

**I am currently trying to create a program that hides folders but for some reason, I am getting this error:**

> with open("desktop.ini", "wt") as configFile:
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'desktop.ini'

**help!!!**

Comment: That looks like an operating system issue.You don't have write access to that location. You can either make sure you have write access to that folder, or use another folder.

Comment: I already tried doing all that when I originally posted the question, but it didn't worked. Though its a long time since I posted this question so I will try this again.